# VERY simple 301 htaccess redirect not working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Very simple URL redirect from:

http://xxxx.net/index.php?k=Nomor-Bangkok&page=0

to:

http://xxxx.net/Nomor-Bangkok/online-0

When I try this (**Old URL to new URL**):

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?k=Nomor-Bangkok&page=0 /Nomor-Bangkok/online-0
```

I get a 200 header response without redirect.

But when I turn it around (**New URL to old URL**):

```
Redirect 301 /Nomor-Bangkok/online-0 /index.php?k=Nomor-Bangkok&page=0
```

Then I get a 301 redirect from new to old URL. But that's not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _“What am i doing wrong?”_ - the Redirect directive works on URL _paths_, but `/index.php?k=Nomor-Bangkok&page=0` is not a path, that is a path (`/index.php`)  _and_ a query string (`?k=Nomor-Bangkok&page=0`)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_alias.html): "mod_alias is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For more complicated tasks such as manipulating the query string, use the tools provided by mod_rewrite."

So, for your exact example, you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^k=Nomor-Bangkok&page=0$ [NC]
RewriteRule index.php /Nomor-Bangkok/online-0? [NC,L,R]
```

or even, as a more general rule if that is what you need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^k=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)&page=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule index.php /%1/online-%2? [NC,L,R]
```

which would redirect `/index.php?k=AnyString&page=AnyNumber` to `/AnyString/online-AnyNumber`

Comment: You are my hero. Works like a charm.
And thx for the info about it.